# Resposta inesperada ao capturar texto de um TextView

Tags: android

Tenho que testar um certo TextView para ver se ele está preenchido no onCreate() da activity e caso ele esteja preenchido, tenho de trocar a imagem de um ImageButton. Estou usando o seguinte código para isso:

```
if (txt_photo_path.getText().toString() != null) {
        btnenviarfoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.enviarfotochecked);
        }
```

No entanto, o código esta rodando sempre. Decidi testar para ver o porque de o TextView sempre estar preenchido, usando o seguinte, dentro do if:

```
Log.w("txt_photo_path", txt_photo_path.getText().toString());
```

O que recebo no meu log está abaixo

```
09-05 12:56:53.161  14726-14726/com.ufscar.ufscar.df100fogo W/txt_photo_path﹕ [ 09-05 12:56:53.381   576:  591 I/ActivityManager ]
```

Por que está acontecendo isso? Como saber se o TextView está realmente vazio ou não?

Comment: `txt_photo_path.getText().toString() != ""` por defeito o `TextView` está sempre preenchido com a string vazia "".

Comment: `txt_photo_path.getText().toString().isEmpty()` ou `txt_photo_path.getText().toString().length() == 0` ou `txt_photo_path.getText().toString().equals("")` é melhor, nunca use comparador `==` com `String`, tome cuidado com a diferença entre `String` no `String Pool` e instâncias dela.

Comment: O @Walkim tem razão, esqueci-me do `.equals("")`. então pode utilizar assim: `if (!txt_photo_path.getText().toString().equals("")) {` com o ponto de exclamação atrás que quer dizer *NOT equals*.

Comment: Usei `(!txt_photo_path.getText().toString().isEmpty())` e funcionou. Obrigado a todos.

Comment: @Wakim formula uma resposta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente o TextView sempre esta preenchido com uma string vazia (""). Bastou trocar

```
if (txt_photo_path.getText().toString() != null)
```

por

```
if (!txt_photo_path.getText().toString().isEmpty())
```

que funcionou perfeitamente.